# How to find offset of Dword where Address Of entry point of an executable is stored

Tags: exe, portable-executable, entry-point

There are disassemblers like CFF explorer which display the `AddressOfEntryPoint` of any executable along with the offset where it is stored. I know how to find that ( `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER::AddressOfEntryPoint` ), but I want to be able to find the **offset** in the PE exe file where the AddressOfEntryPoint is stored, programmatically.

I've read a lot about PE files [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx)

But still can't figure it out. Help needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offset of `AddressOfEntryPoint` would be the sum of the size of the sections that precede it: `sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER)`+`sizeof(DWORD)`+`sizeof(IMAGE_FILE_HEADER)`+`sizeof(WORD)`+`sizeof(BYTE)`+`sizeof(BYTE)`+`sizeof(DWORD)`+`sizeof(DWORD)`+`sizeof(DWORD)`

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like @JosephH wrote *correct* answer, however that answer isn't correct correct and not nice at all.

To get EP you need to have read file as binary file (not all file is needed).

So assume you have `unsigned char* data;` which points to binary info.

```
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* dosHeader = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *)data;                       //cast it to DOS header (some calls it MZ header)
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* peHeader = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *)&data[dosHeader->e_lfanew];  //find NT header (PE header)
DWORD ep = 0;
if (peHeader->Magic == 0x10b)  //32-bit executable
    ep = ((IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 *)peHeader)->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;  //Get EP
else  //64-bit executable
    ep = ((IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64 *)peHeader)->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;  //Get EP
```

I think my answer is better because it is more self explaining, also you cannot trust offsets, because structures changes time to time. As you see even `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` that I used is defined differently on x86 and x64 machines.